# How to submit() an input with type="search" with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, submit, form-submit

I'm building a WordPress theme. I've added an optional feature for page transitions. The concept behind it is simple: a user clicks a link, jQuery intercepts that links with `event.preventDefault()`, jQuery removes a specific class from the body element and after 300ms the link is loaded yet.

Now I have a problem withs forms. The user can add one search form the the header and one (or multiple) in the sidebar/widget areas.

All forms have less or more the same structure (there is some PHP inside):

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="ambition-search-form header_search override" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <input type="search" class="ambition-search-field header_search override" id="ambition-search-field-input-header_search"
            placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'ambition_text_searchfield', 'Start typing...' ) ); ?>"
            value="" name="s"
            title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'ambition_title_searchfield', 'Search for pages, articles and documents.' ) ); ?>"
            autocomplete="off" />
        <input type="submit" class="ambition-search-submit header_search override" value="" />
</form>
```

The problem with the forms is that the site goes to the search results page when the user hits enter. Hitting enter isn't a link and therefore jquery can't intercept it, like it does with links. To fix this, I've created the following code:

```
function ambition_submit(e) {

    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        console.log('SUBMIT');

        event.preventDefault(); //Stop the link from going (by submitting it)
    
        if ($('body').hasClass('ambition-loaded')) { //For safety
            $('body').removeClass('ambition-loaded');   //Remove the .ambition-loaded class
    

        if (!event) {
            e = window.event;
        }
        
        var ambition_target = event.target || e.srcElement;

        console.log(ambition_target);

            //And set a timeout and move the browser to the url
            setTimeout(function() {
                ambition_target.submit();
            }, 300);      
        
        }
}
}


document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('keypress', ambition_submit);
})
```

I'll shortly explain it, although it quite speaks for itself.
AddEventlistener when the user types in one of the forms. A function `ambition_submit` is called. The function checkes whether the user hit 'enter'. If yes, we use preventDefault. The class `ambition-loaded` is removed from the body. I store the element on which the event occurred in a variable. (It is logged to the console.) I set a timeout of 300ms and after that the page should be redirected.

In the above code, `ambition_target.submit();` doesn't work (`.click()` doesn't work either).

How do I submit the input field?

(Or, how do I delay the submitting of the form for 300ms and in meantime execute a function which removes the class?)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your "forms" aren't really forms, but input-elements and therefore don't have a submit-method. Hitting the enter-key shouldn't submit input-fields outside a form either, so the question is, what is causing the navigation to the search results page?

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for checking it out. I didn't now this. I guess it  has something to do with the following element: `<input type="submit" class="ambition-search-submit override" value="">`. This input with type=submit is after the original input, but is hidden using `display:none`. (The code for the search form was copied in its original form and modified by my.) Would it be possible to replace the `input tag` with `form`? Or do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Never mind my suggestion of replacing it with a `form` tag. I just checked the source code out again and I saw that there already was a `form` container. I'll update the question with the full code.

Comment: I got it working! I used the `parentElement` to get the `form` element and then used submit on it. Thanks! If you want, you can submit your suggestion of submitting the `<form>` as answer @AndreNuechter!

Comment: Thx, that's all right. Glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` tag is a child element of the `form` tag. The `.submit()` doesn't work on `input` tags, as that is not a form as whole. Selecting the parent `form` tag and submitting that instead did it.

Thanks to [Andre Nuechter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7732282/andre-nuechter).